# How to query nested hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

What is the quickest way in Ruby to retrieve the correct hash by `language` from the following nested hash:

```
COUNTRIES = {
  "DE" => {:currency => "EUR", :tax_rates => [19, 7], :languages => ["de-de"]},
  "US" => {:currency => "USD", :tax_rates => [10], :languages => ["en-us"]}
}
```

I managed to retrieve the correct hash by providing the `currency`:

```
COUNTRIES.select{|key, hash| hash[:currency] == "USD" }
```

But how can I query by a `language`, for example by `en-us`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COUNTRIES.select{|key, hash| hash[:languages].include?("en-us")}`

of note, if you're only looking for a singular result, it's cheaper to use `#detect` than it is to use `#select.first`